# Handling basic ajax events in Primefaces Components

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

First of all I'm still learning the structure and how it works.
I searched around the web to get an suitable and easy answer to the following question:

Is there a way to regonize all other basic ajax events, like hovering and clicking on Primefaces Components?

For example, i would know the event which get invoked if you click on the previous or next button on an `<p:schedule>`. The documentation says there are only "dateSelect, eventMove, eventResize" and "eventSelect" as callable ajax events. But this is not enough, if you want to build an complex application and you combine an `<p:calendar>` with an `<p:schedule>`. There you need to know when the schedule switches the month or year.

I hope someone can give me an clear and understandable answer to this.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not specify what event you need, your answer is going to be as clear as the question.

The primefaces objects can only recognize the events they are programmed to. If you need to get a specific type of event, you can:

1) see if the primefaces support that event. put it in a `<p:ajax` tag, and see if it works.

2) see if the standard JSF ajax API support it.

3) If all else fails, you can try to put a jQuery script along with the page, to handle the event and make a call from the client side.

---

The `<p:calendar` and `<p:schedule` makes heavy use of jQuery plugins to render it, I doubt you can get the events on the month selector or anything else in the rendered interface without client-side jquery.